# Custom getLine() function for c

Tags: c, string, getline

I need a function/method that will take in a char array and set it to a string read from stdin. It needs to return the last character read as its return type, so I can determine if it  reached the end of a line or the end of file marker.

here is what I have so far, and I kind of based it off of code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375604/reading-in-a-string-of-unknown-length-from-the-console)

UPDATE: I changed it, but now it just crashes upon hitting enter after text. I know this way is inefficient, and char is not the best for EOF check, but for now I am just trying to get it to return the string. I need it to do it in this fashion and no other fashion. I need the string to be the exact length of the line, and to return a value that is either the newline or EOF int which I believe can still be used in a char value.

This program is in C not C++

```
char getLine(char **line);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *line;
    char returnVal = 0;

    returnVal = getLine(&line);
    printf("%s", line);

    free(line);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

char getLine(char **line) {
    unsigned int lengthAdder = 1, counter = 0, size = 0;
    char charRead = 0;

    *line = malloc(lengthAdder);
    while((charRead = getc(stdin)) != EOF && charRead != '\n')
    {
        *line[counter++] = charRead;
        *line = realloc(*line, counter);
    }

    *line[counter] = '\0';

    return charRead;
}
```

Thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: Do you want C or C++? The *proper* solution is quite different in each language. Also note that more interesting than the value of the last character read is the number of characters read. You can always look at that position in the read string to determine what the character was. Additionally the multiple `realloc` will be probably inefficient.

Comment: In addition to what H2CO3 said, you're not `return`ing anything from `getLine` although you declared it to be returning a `char`. Also, you shouldn't `realloc` for every character, do that in chunks of sensible size. And `line = realloc(line, counter);` means you lose the reference to the memory if `realloc` fails, use a temporary to save the result of `realloc` and check whether it is `NULL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your key problem is that ***line*** pointer value does not propagate out of the **getLine()** function. The solution is to pass *pointer to the **line** pointer* to the function as a parameter instead - calling it like `getLine(&line);` while the function would be defined as taking parameter `char **line`. In the function, on all places where you now work with **line**, you would work with ***line** instead, i.e. dereferencing the pointer to a pointer and working with the value of the variable in **main()** where the pointer leads. Hope this is not too confusing. :-) Try to draw it on a piece of paper.

(A tricky part - you must change `line[counter]` to `(*line)[counter]` because you *first* need to dereference the pointer to the string, and only *then* to access a specific character in the string.)

There is a couple of other problems with your code:

- You use **char** as the type for **charRead**. However, the **EOF** constant cannot be represented using **char**, you need to use **int** - both as the type of **charRead** and return value of **getLine()**, so that you can actually distringuish between a newline and end of file.
- You forgot to return the last char read from your **getLine()** function. :-)
- You are reallocating the buffer after each character addition. This is not terribly efficient and therefore is a rather ugly programming practice. It is not too difficult to use another variable to track the amount of space allocated and then (i) start with allocating a reasonable chunk of memory, e.g. 64 bytes, so that ideally you will never reallocate (ii) enlarge the allocation only if you need to based on comparing the counter and your allocation size tracker. Two reallocation strategies are common - either doubling the size of the allocation or increasing the allocation by a fixed step.

Comment: I know it is inefficient as of now, I am just trying to get it to return the string atm. I will worry about everything else when I get it to return the string. I changed the params to **char, and passed it be address, and chenged it to where within the function it sets everything by *line. Now it just crashes upon open

Comment: A tricky part - you must change `line[counter]` to `(*line)[counter]` because you *first* need to dereference the pointer to the string, and only *then* to access a specific character in the string. Does that help? If not, exactly where it crashes? Try running it in a debugger.

Comment: Yah I changed it an it crashes after entering in text. Before if I put a printf within the function, it did get the string just fine, but would not return it. I understand I was passing it by-value, and so it was not getting saved to the original. Now I can;t check it at all. The updated code is above

Comment: In your updated code, you still use `*line[counter]` instead of `(*line)[counter]`. A simple rule of thumb for order of evaluation is that (i) first, anything *after* a variable name is evaluated, (ii) then anything *before* it. So for `*line[counter]`, `[counter]` (array lookup) is done *before* `*` (straight pointer dereference)

Answer (score 2):

You're assigning the result of `malloc()` to a local copy of `line`, so after the `getLine()` function returns it's not modified (albeit you think it is). What you have to do is either return it (as opposed to use an output parameter) or pass its address (pass it 'by reference'):

```
void getLine(char **line)
{
    *line = malloc(length);

    // etc.
}
```

and call it like this:

```
char *line;
getLine(&line);
```

Comment: I changed it to this, but now it crashes upon entering data. The changed code is updated in the op.

Comment: @Tookie On SO we don't write entire solutions for you, sorry. This was *the* fundamental idea you missed - beyond that, please learn using a debugger, google a good tutorial on pointers etc.

Answer (score 0):

The way you use `realloc` is not correct. If it returns `NULL` then the memory block will be lost.

It is better to use `realloc` in this way:

```
char *tmp;
...
tmp = realloc(line, counter);
if(tmp == NULL)
   ERROR, TRY TO SOLVE IT
line = tmp;
```

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't answer the question. This should be a comment, not an answer.