# Validating input is of certain length in C

Tags: c

My program requires the user to enter input consisting of 16 characters (excluding null terminator) twice then store it in separate strings. Here is my current code:

```
void takeInput16(char *inputStr, int size){
do{
    printf("Enter a string of length 16\n");
    fgets(inputStr, size, stdin);
  } while(!(inputStr[size - 2] == '\n' && inputStr[size - 3] != '\0'));
}

int main(){
  char *num1 = malloc(18 * sizeof(char));
  char *num2 = malloc(18 * sizeof(char));
  takeInput16(num1, 18);
  takeInput16(num2, 18);


  return 0;
}
```

This works fine for detection of input of less than 16 characters however it does not handle input being longer than 16 characters as it causes multiple calls to fgets to occur.

My question is, how can I safely take input in C and ensure it is of a certain size in terms of characters (I want to reject input which is too long rather than simply truncating the extra characters)

Comment: As a general rule, if you want input of size N, never just use `fgets` or `scanf` with an array of size N (or N+1) — because at best that will "truncate the extra characters".  Usually it's best to read *everything* the user types, then check it and print errors as appropriate.  Can you use an array of size, say, 1024?  Does your program have to behave correctly if the user types more characters than that before hitting Enter?

Comment: Try to read char by char counting them. You can return a integer that represents if the input passed the max length or not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading in a string of unknown length from the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375604/reading-in-a-string-of-unknown-length-from-the-console)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input is ASCII, you can read the characters one by one using `fgetc` until buffer is full or `\n` is detected. If buffer is full, keep reading until `\n` is detected, as the example below.

Note that this example will read up to 4 characters when size is 5, it needs room for the null-terminating character at the end. The `EOF` check is not necessary for `stdin` but you might as well put it there in case input is redirected.

```
int takeInputx(char* buf, int bufsize)
{
    buf[bufsize - 1] = '\0';
    for (int i = 0; ; i++)
    {
        int ch = fgetc(stdin);
        int end = (ch == '\n' || ch == EOF);
        if (i < bufsize - 1)
            buf[i] = end ? '\0' : (char)ch;
        if (end)
            return i;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() 
{
    int size = 5;
    char* num1 = malloc(size * sizeof(char));
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        int res = takeInputx(num1, size);
        printf("%s, string len %d, exceeds max size? %d\n", 
            num1, strlen(num1), res >= size);
    }
    free(num1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not properly check the input: the null byte should be at offset `size - 1` and the newline at offset `size - 2`, but most importantly you should check that `fgets()` did not fail and that the length of the input is `size - 1`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void takeInput(char *inputStr, int size) {
    for (;;) {
        printf("Enter a string of length %d\n", size - 2);
        if (!fgets(inputStr, size, stdin)) {
            perror("input error");
            abort();
        }
        if (strlen(inputStr) < size - 1) {
            printf("input too short, need %d bytes\n", size - 2);
            continue;
        }
        if (inputStr[size - 2] != '\n') {
            int c;
            /* read and discard the rest of the input line */
            while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
                continue;
            printf("input too long, need %d bytes\n", size - 2);
            continue;
        }
        inputStr[size - 2] = '\0';  /* strip the newline */
        break;
    }
}

int main() {
    char *num1 = malloc(18 * sizeof(char));
    char *num2 = malloc(18 * sizeof(char));
    takeInput(num1, 18);
    takeInput(num2, 18);

    printf("num1: %s\n", num1);
    printf("num2: %s\n", num2);

    free(num1);
    free(num2);
    return 0;
}
```