# Resizing character array in c

Tags: c++, arrays, winapi, char

A MFC coder want to learn some basic about character array intialisation and deletion of element.Take following examples compare with MFC (there is CString so no need of memory allocation or de allocation but same needed in c.)
**(don't have std::string interface )**

***Example 1:-***

To construct string we us following code in MFC.

```
CString constructString;    
constructString = "";    
constructString = "ABC";    
constructString = constructString + "PQR";    
constructString = constructString + "LMN";
```

whatever size of string we have this will work.

for C i used following code

```
#define DEFAULT_ARRAY_SIZE          20000    
char* constructString  = new char[DEFAULT_ARRAY_SIZE];    
strcpy(constructString ,"");    
strcat(constructString ,"ABC");    
strcat(constructString ,"PQR");    
strcat(constructString ,"LMN");
```

***Problem :-***

1)Code will work fine till my char* constructString size is less than 20000 but when it exceed i dont have solution,how to resize my array so it will take more charecters.

2)I intialize char* constructString with 20000 but when my string is very small of size 10 then my remaining 18990 charecters are wasted or not i dont know,will this effect my executable perfomance.If yes then how to delete my remaining dummy charecters.

***Example 2:-***

To read content from file we use following code in MFC.

```
CStdioFile ReadFile;    
ReadFile.Open("Sample.txt",CFile::typeText|CFile::Read);    
CString CurrentString;    
CStringArray WholeFile;    
while(ReadFile.ReadString(CurrentString))    
{    
    WholeFile.Add(CurrentString);    
}
```

Whitever size of File it will work fine.

For C i use following code

```
#define MAX_FILE_SIZE               65534    
FILE *ptr_file;    
const char* list[MAX_FILE_SIZE];    
wchar_t CurrentString[1000];    
ptr_file =fopen("Sample.txt","rb");    
int __index = 0;    
while(fgetws (CurrentString , 1000 , ptr_file) != NULL)    
{    
    char* errorDes;    
    errorDes = new char[1000];    
    wcstombs(errorDes, CurrentString, 1000);    
    list[__index] = errorDes;    
    __index++;    
}
```

***Problem :-***

1)Same as above if my one line charecters exceed 1000 then more than 1000 charecters are not consider and vise versa.

2)If my file size exceed 65534 then char* list array will not fill properly and vise versa.

---

Please provide me any link,block of code,suggestion that help me to solve all problem in pure C.

Comment: `new char[1000]` is not `C`. You may want to have look at `realloc` not sure what is `C++` equivalent for it.

Comment: I already go through that but do you have any example??

Comment: As pointed out, `new` is `cpp`. If you need to use `new` have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737226/regrow-memory-allocated-by-operator-new) discussion for ur 1st qn.

Comment: I agree that i have to see that discussion but as you say new is c++ operator so use std for string manupulation but i cant because,usage of std:: is not allowed by my seniors.

Comment: @user1035089 According to the chosen answer to that qn, If in case you have to resize memry allocated by `new`, you need to reallocate. Or else you will have to make use of `std::vector` etc. If you want to use `new` not `malloc` etc retag ur qn too so it can attract `cpp` people

Comment: i want to use new and malloc instead of std::vector

Comment: Are you using C or C++ ? In C you cannot use new, it doesn't exist. If you want to use malloc, you have to do everthing "by hand", that is if the buffer becomes too small, then you must make it bigger, for example with the realloc function.

Comment: i am using c++ but except string.

Answer (score 0):

**In C**

```
    #define DEFAULT_ARRAY_SIZE          20000
    #define NEW_SIZE                    20100  

    char* constructString  = (char *)malloc(DEFAULT_ARRAY_SIZE * sizeof(char));
    // Now you have the array allocated

    // To reallocate it:
    constructSring = (char *)realloc (construcString, NEW_SIZE)

    // Now you can assign new values into the new array positions:
    constructString[20000] = 'a'
    constructString[20001] = 'b'
    constructString[20002] = 'c'
    ...
```

I hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

You can create a vector of chars with variable length in C, copying the behaviour of `std::string`.

I gave complete source code in an answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598351/reading-strings-with-undefined-length-in-c).

Basically, you need to create various functions (`String_add`, `String_getLine`, `String_delete`...) around a struct which will hold the pointer to char vector, the size and the capacity. In order to minimize the number of memory allocations, you can follow the `std::string` strategy, doubling the capacity each time.

Hope this helps.